# Python: Loop a list of functions and asset result

Tags: python, list, function, loops

I need to loop a list of functions which return a "Success/0" or "Fail/1".

i have the list of functions

```
cmd_list = [a(x, y , z), b(e, f, g)]
```

and i iterate thought it

```
for cmd in cmd_list:
    if cmd:
        break
```

The function run as expected in the sequence, however, any of the functions returning False / 1 , does not seem to break the loop.

Comment: What, exactly, do the functions return? You seem to indicate they return a non-empty string, which should always evaluate to true, and so the loop would *always* break.

Comment: Just a slight correction, you are not iterating a list of functions, you are iterating a list of results from said functions. By the time you are iterating, the function was already executed.

Comment: they return 1 or 0, which should evaluate to true or false if i'm not mistaken

Comment: hmmm, ok so.. the functions have already completed before even doing the assesment... does anybody know a way of achieving this elegantly?

Comment: Integer 1 and 0, or string "1" and "0"? Integer 1 and both strings would evaluate as true; only integer 0 is false.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any need to delay the function calls until you iterate over the list; the end result (iterating over the return values of the calls) is the same.

Comment: Why don't failing function calls raise an error?

Comment: @chepner except if the functions are expensive and he want's to short-circuit execution. But I'm not sure if that's actually what he wants.

Comment: @Flamespeaker: store the function reference and the arguments separately, and only apply when looping?

Comment: @LukasGraf That's true.

Comment: @Flamespeaker: Added an answer demonstrating how to do that. But this is unrelated to you issues with breaking the loop. A return value of integer `1` *will* break the loop, so I'm pretty sure one of your functions doesn't return what you think it does (or has side-effects that change their arguments). If you need help with that, you should post the code for those functions and their arguments.

Comment: @LukasGraf: I tried replacing the integer 1 and 0's by True or False. did not change a thing.

from what i saw from my logging it would seem that the comment by user3557327 makes sense and that i was indeed looping the results of the functions instead of looping the functions 1 by 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual technique to stop if something goes wrong without having to check for errors after each step is to use exceptions.  Make all your functions raise some error if they fail, e.g.

```
class CommandError(Exception): pass
```

and then simply call them one by one, catching the exception after the block:

```
try:
    a(x, y , z)
    b(e, f, g)
except CommandError as e:
    # error handling
else:
    # successfully finished
```

Comment: Thanks Sven, this did the trick for me. i removed the return and changed the error handling to "raise Exception(error_message)". i would upvote but it seems i do not have enought points :(

Comment: @Flamespeaker: You can still "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark on the left, if you want to mark your question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?:

```
cmd_list = [lambda: a(x,y), lambda: b(),...]  
for cmd in cmd_list:  
    if cmd():  
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delay execution of those functions until you iterate, you can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

cmd_list = [partial(a, x, y, z), partial(b, e, f, g)]

for func in cmd_list:
    if func():
        break
```

`partial(f, a, b, c)` will create a new function-like object, that when called, will return the result of function `f` called with the arguments `a, b, c`.

This is unrelated to your issue with breaking the loop though: I'm pretty sure one of your functions simply doesn't return what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, testing for 1 is true and 0 is false. You should change your functions to return 1 for success and 0 for failure.

Comment: Maybe this would be a little more Pythonic (although `True` and `False` are better than `1` and `0`, and exceptions may be the way to go), but it won't solve the issue here.

Comment: No indeed, all my functions return 1 or 0 , if that was the case it should have jumped to loop where i did not expect it.